# To Give shortcutkey to contextstrip items in run time

Tags: c#

I am adding a list of items to a context strip at runtime. Is it possible to add a shortcut key to these items at run time...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `MenuItem`s, you can just assign to their [`Shortcut` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.shortcut.aspx):

```
var menuItem = contextMenu.MenuItems[0];
menuItem.Shortcut = Shortcut.CtrlS;
```

You'll probably also want to set the `ShowShortcut` property to true so that the shortcut is displayed next to the menu item.